# Server denied check_authentication after migration of Drupal

Tags: authentication, migration, docker, drupal, openid

I just moved a drupal website from one server to another.
On the original server the site was set up directly in apache.
On the new server, i have a docker layer in between:

The machine runs a debian system with docker, and the (currently only) docker container features a debian/apache2/mysql/php setup.
The container's ports 80 and 443 are exposed to the outside, and the migrated website works just fine. With one exception:

The migrated drupal website contains an openid_provider module. I used this to login to other sites. However, since the migration this function has broken:
On most of the sites i try to login using openid (other drupal sites, wordpress, mediawiki) the login fails. These sites raise messages in the form "OpenID verification failed: Server denied check_authentication".

Fun fact: openid login still works on stackexchange sites ;)

Does anyone have a clue what is going on? There's no (related) errors or warnings in the apache logs - neither on the open_id providing, migrated site, nor in the client logs.

I don't have an idea where and how to start debugging. Let me know, if you need more details.

Here's the drupal module i use: https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_provider (I know, it's deprecated).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check your Drupal logs.

Comment: i enabled openid_provider debug mode.
on the provider side, i get success notes:
automatic response authentication success using redirect to https://ah-dienste.de/openid/authenticate?destination=node/12 (request dump:

`array (
  'q' => 'openid/provider',
  'openid.mode' => 'checkid_setup',
  'openid.identity' => 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select',
  'openid.assoc_handle' => '...',
  'openid.return_to' => '...',
  'openid.ns' => '...',
  'openid.claimed_id' => 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select',
  'openid.realm' => 'https://ah-dienste.de/',
 ...
)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be a name resolution related problem:

All sites, for which the auth request failed lay on the same server.
This server had an entry in /etc/hosts which resolved the domain name of the OpenID provider website to its *old* ip. After removing that entry, everything works fine.

This also explains, why it works for some other services (which are hosted on other servers).

Fun fact: I spent 3 days debugging the Drupal OpenId module, just overseeing the obvious.